# Restricting Desktop access in Windows 8 Metro application

Tags: javascript, windows, windows-8, microsoft-metro

I'm currently developing a Windows 8 Metro application (javascript) in Visual Studio 2012 for a public gallery competition entry which will run on a tablet PC. Ordinarily, I would never ask a question like this, but I've considered the application at length and this seems legitimate enough of a requirement. The application is simple in that it has three screens presented to the user:

1. Call to Action
2. User Details
3. Thank you

Given that this application will need to run all day is straightforward enough, but stopping saavy passers-by from shutting down the application and opening Internet Explorer and leaving the tablet on a less than desirable webpage is something I don't want to be called about.

Of course I can set a Restricted Group Policy on Application Access but that doesn't stop users from pressing the Start button and suspending the application.

My question is this: Is it possible to implement a password dialog or specific keystroke combination that prevents the application from being suspending, gesture suspended or shut  down which stops the user from accessing anything other than the intended application?

Comment: sounds like you want run in a kiosk mode? [this thread](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/winappsuidesign/thread/9871c3d8-b484-4c85-b8d2-4d762591ff86) may be of interest.  It pre-release era, but I don't think the scenario has changed.

Comment: You can create another non-WinRT application which could reload your app, return focus to it, and close IE instances.

Comment: Thank you both for the constructive responses...Windows 8 embedded (kiosk mode) does sound like a good alternative, but given the time period, probably not feasible. Group Policy Template is probably the best option at this stage - Windows 8 does appear to have clamped down on applications manipulating the host operating system.